# Node MariaDB stuck on getConnection

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mariadb

I'm running mariadb locally and want to query for a few rows using the Node driver.
I have the following code below that comes straight from the mariadb node docs. I've confirmed my server is up and running and that I can query from the CLI itself.

The weird thing is that the script doesn't fail or throw error. It just gets stuck at the `await pool.getConnection()` line. I even waited for like 5 minutes.

My server version is `Server version: 10.7.3-MariaDB Homebrew` and I'm using the `3.0.0` package version for Node https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'node',
        password: 'PWD',
        connectionLimit: 5,
        port: 3306,
        database: 'DB',
        acquireTimeout: 5000
});

(async () => {
        console.log('in iife');
        let conn;  
        try {
           console.log('awaiting conn');

           //This never gets reached..just gets stuck even after 5s
           conn = await pool.getConnection();
           console.log(conn);
           console.log('awaiting q');
           const rows = await conn.query("SELECT * FROM foo where id=1");
           console.log(rows);
        } catch (err) {
                throw err;
        } finally {
            if (conn) return conn.end();
        }

})();
```

I've actually tried this on two separate devices and have the same exact issue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a red herring. Using dev tools to debug led me to realize there was a mundane runtime error in undeclared var. Red herring was that error was being caught and thrown. But bc this was being called as ad-hoc script, I was never aware of what the error was. Replacing the throw with a console.error led me to see error